# Are these essentially the same tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-burnination

I've noticed a lot of edits for [microsoft-office-365](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-365) some of which I voted to accept some I didn't for various reasons. I've now noticed a few edits for [exchangeonline](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchangeonline) and reviewed them in the normal way. After doing so I asked myself actually are these the same essentially the same. I made some edits to remove the exchangeonline tag from a few questions (In hindsight, I should of asked this question first. I will go back and fix those edits if people agree we should have both)

The [exchangeonline](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchangeonline) tag is written as though it is only the exchange part of the office-365 service, that makes sense. However as it is part of that service surely the [microsoft-office-365](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-office-365) tag is both accurate and sufficient?

Should we burn [exchangeonline](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchangeonline)?

Comment: FYI there is also the option to merge tags, rather than burning them.

Comment: I've never seen that option anywhere, but that's good to know for the future

Comment: More specifically, moderators have the option to merge tags. It's not something a regular user can do within the software.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't. Even when Office 365 contains Exchange Online, Exchange Online could be subscribed as a standalone service which don't necessarily have the Office Suite apps.

https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-office-365-for-business-plans

https://products.office.com/en-us/exchange/compare-microsoft-exchange-online-plans

Comment: But the exchange part is the same is it not?

Comment: @Drifter104 see it the other way, exchange online does not contains office 365 stuff. its like tagging microsoft office for a microsoft word problem, I think

Comment: @yagmoth555 I'm not sure in that instance  Microsoft Office would be the wrong tag. I think I'm maybe looking at it from an answer/question pov. If I want to find something about my exchange online subscription would a q tagged o365 lead me to the wrong answer.  The other angle is then, is it right to tag questions with both tags?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Felipe. I wanted to add this as a comment, but it is too long. So ...

Exchange is not Office. The Office 365 suite is a collection of end-user tools like Word, Excel or Outlook that can be obtained via a subscription license, as opposed to Office 2016 which is obtained through a one-off payment. Exchange Online, or Exchange 2016 respectively, is not an end-user tool, but a software that provides the service of mail delivery.

Those are two very distinct pieces of software and you could very well be a master in deploying and configuring Office 365, but have zero knowledge about Exchange Online, or vice versa.

Dropping `exchangeonline` in favor of `microsoft-office-365` would be inaccurate and also misleading and maybe resulting in less attention by exchange experts.

Comment: You say that but majority of people ask using the office-365 tag, and those are answered fairly regularly. Yet `exchangeonline` has one 20 questions, and actually I've just noticed `exchange-online` was merged into office-365 tag at some point historically. Also the description for the tag includes server side components.